# reverse linked list recursively - different function signature

Tags: c, recursion, singly-linked-list

There are many posts with probably with same question but the problem says it has to be done by

```
 node* reverseList (node * lh)
                              {
                               if(lh==NULL)............ ;

                                else if (lh->next==NULL)...........;

                                else ...........;
                              }
```

the three blanks must be filled
the first two are simply

```
return NULL
```

and

```
return lh
```

repectively

one way could be just to go down and reverse the pointers but in that case how can i keep the tail intact even after backtracking? is it possible at all?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The trick to solving recursive problems is to pretend that you are done already. To solve this homework by yourself, you need to answer three questions:

- How do you reverse an empty list? (i.e. a list with `lh` set to `NULL`)?
- How do you reverse a list with only one item?
- If someone could reverse all items on the list except the initial one for you, where do you add the first item from the initial list to the pre-reversed "tail" portion of the list?

You answered the first two already: `NULL` and `lh` are the right answers. Now think of the third one:

```
else {
    node *reversedTail = reverseList(lh->next);
    ...
}
```

At this point, `reversedTail` contains pre-reversed tail of your list. All you need to do is set lh->next to NULL, add it to the back of the list that you are holding, and return `reversedTail`. The final code looks like this:

```
else {
    node *reversedTail = reverseList(lh->next);
    node *p = reversedTail; 
    while (p->next) p = p->next;
    p->next = lh;
    lh->next = NULL;
    return reversedTail;
}
```

Comment: Real nice answer! Clear, complete, and gives the rationale.

Comment: this not actually a homework problem but a previous year's sem end test paper ..anyways do you mean to do something like this?                tail = reverse(lh->next);
lh->next = NULL;
return tail; 
i am not  getting what are we trying to do

Comment: @AseemDua No, that code is not complete, because `lh` gets lost. You need to traverse the tail until you see an element with `next` set to `NULL`, and assign `lh` to that element's `next`.

Comment: thats what is said by reversing the pointers.. but when i back track the original tail gets lost.. how do i retain it?

Comment: oh thanks now i get how did we retain the tail.. i was trying equating p to lh than tail which left me with nothing to hold/return the new tail.. the while loop was the tricky part

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/5780/discussion-between-aseem-dua-and-dasblinkenlight)

Answer (score 2):

I think this answers it:

```
node *reverseList(node *lh)
{
    if (!lh) return NULL;
    else if (!lh->next) return lh;
    else {
        node *new_head = reverseList(lh->next);
        lh->next->next = lh;
        lh->next = NULL;
        return new_head;
    }
}
```

It returns the head of the reversed list, i.e. the tail of the original list.

```
head = reverse_list(head);
```

Answer (score 1):

Below is an API which does the reversal of a Single linked list, this one of the best algo that i have seen:

```
void iterative_reverse() 
{ 

    mynode *p, *q, *r; 

    if(head == (mynode *)0) 
    { return; 
    } 

    p = head; 
    q = p->next; 
    p->next = (mynode *)0; 

    while (q != (mynode *)0) 
    { 
        r = q->next; 
        q->next = p; 
        p = q; 
        q = r; 
    } 
    head = p; 
 }
```